# Mongodb - find query based on an element of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have the following type of document where I have to find instock elements based on a given value. i.e Return all instocks where `ele = 5`.

```
{"item":"journal",
 "instock":[
    { "warehouse":"A", "ele":[2,4,5] },
    { "warehouse":"C", "ele":[8,5,2] },
    { "warehouse":"F", "ele":[3] },
    { "warehouse":"K", "ele":[2,8,4] }
    ]
}
```

I tried to use $elemMatch but it just produces the first element.

```
db.inventory.find({"item": "journal"}, {"_id": 0, "item": 0, "instock":{$elemMatch: {"ele": {$in: [5]}}} })
```

But it just gives:

```
{ "instock" : [ 
    { "warehouse" : "A", "ele" : [ 2, 4, 5 ] }
]}
```

And the expectation is

```
{ "instock" : [ 
    { "warehouse" : "A", "ele" : [ 2, 4, 5 ] },
    { "warehouse" : "C", "ele" : [ 8, 5, 2 ] }
]}
```

How should I get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$elemMatch` or `instock.$` will return first match document in find()'s projection,

You can use [aggregation expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#projection) in projection from MongoDB 4.4, for your example use array [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator in projection,

```
db.collection.find({
  "item": "journal"
},
{
  instock: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$instock",
      cond: { $in: [5, "$$this.ele"] }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LIVOwQhM_FD)

---

For the old version you can use `aggregate()` using above same operator.

Comment: I think what you are suggesting is to use aggregation. Because $filter is not supporting in "find". So the working answer I created based on your answer is db.inventory.aggregate({ $match:{"item": "journal"}}, { $project: {instock: { $filter: { input: "$instock", cond: { $in: [5, "$$this. ele"] }}}}})

Comment: yes its perfect, what is the version of your mongodb?

Comment: I'm using 4.2.1

Comment: updated answer, its support in mongodb 4.4, glad you have resolved your problem with aggregate().

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to unwind the `instock` array, then filter the data, and finally if you want you can group the result by `item` to obtain the desired result.

Here is an exemple: [solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xZ-6w-Rnleo)